# Dynamically change property attributes

Tags: matlab, properties, attributes, private-members

There are dependent properties in class A, based on an argument in constructor I want to make some of properties Hidden, so that user will not be able to set/get these properties.

```
classdef A
    properties (Dependent = true)
        prop1
        prop2
    end

    methods
        function value = get.prop1(obj)
        ...
        end
        function value = get.prop2(obj)
        ...
        end
    end

    methods(Access = public)
         function obj = A(arg1)
             if arg1 == 1
                  % make prop1 Hidden for the constructed object
             end
         end
    end
end
```

and here is sample usages:

```
a1 = A(2);
a1.prop1;   % ok
a2 = A(1);
a2.prop1;   % problem, user will not know about existence prop1
```

Comment: Where did you get this idea? I've never seen an OOP language that lets you change property attributes dynamically (unless you consider reflection, which I don't think is a thing for MATLAB classes). As mentioned by NewEyes, I'd just go with 2 different classes.

Comment: @Dev-iL in Smalltalk, one of the root OO-languages, everything is defined dynamically, classes and methods

Comment: @Dev-iL I know about OOP. I can solve with classes, of course. But I am trying to find a non-OO solution. Additionally, MATLAB is different than other OO languages. According to some opinions, MATLAB is a scripting language. So I want to use script side of the MATLAB.

Comment: In MATLAB you can create properties dynamically and assign attributes to it, https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/dynamic-properties-adding-properties-to-an-instance.html. What I am looking for is that whether same is possible with non-dynamic properties or not?

Answer (score 3):

The `Access` level is fixed, as in any OOP language I know. It is *fundamental* to how the class interacts with other code.

Your only workaround is to use `Dependent` properties of a `matlab.mixin.SetGet` type class, and have a conditional behaviour based on the construction argument. Here is a `POC` class to demonstrate:

**Class:**

```
classdef POC < matlab.mixin.SetGet
    properties ( Dependent = true )
        prop
    end
    properties ( Access = private )
        arg   % Construction argument to dictate obj.prop behaviour
        prop_ % Private stored value of prop
    end
    methods
        function obj = POC( arg )
            % constructor
            obj.prop = 'some value'; % Could skip setting this if argCheck fails
            obj.arg = arg;
        end

        % Setter and getter for "prop" property do obj.argCheck() first.
        % This throws an error if the user isn't permitted to set/get obj.prop
        function p = get.prop( obj )
            obj.argCheck();
            p = obj.prop_;
        end
        function set.prop( obj, p )                
            obj.argCheck();
            obj.prop_ = p;
        end
    end
    methods ( Access = private )
        function argCheck( obj )
            % This function errors if the property isn't accessible
            if obj.arg == 1
                error( 'Property "prop" not accessible when POC.arg == 1' );
            end
        end
    end
end
```

**Output**

```
>> A = POC(1);
l>> A.prop
Error using POC/get.prop (line 17)
Property "prop" not accessible when POC.arg == 1 
>> A = POC(2);
>> A.prop
ans =
    'some value'
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I'd create two different classes, one with hidden and one with visible attributes.

In that case you can just set the corresponding property attributes in the hidden class. This should do it:

```
properties (Dependent = true, Hidden = True, GetAccess=private, SetAccess=private)
```

Comment: If arg1 is not 1, then all properties will be visible to the user. After typing object name, user will see all properties with tab completion. In your solution they will be hidden regardless of arg1 in constructor.

Comment: Ah okay, I understand now! Why don't you just use 2 different classes for each case?

Comment: You are right, but I dont want to create classes for different reasons. I have tens of properties (not only two), I gave just a simple example to show my problem briefly.

Comment: Even if you have a lot a of properties that still just ctrl+c and ctrl+v and change one line. Are there other complications you did not mention so far?

Comment: @NewEyes There are lots of reasons why multiple similar classes are less preferable to a single flexible class. What if you want to modify how a function works? Now you've got to edit it in many class files. I think there are better workarounds, or the OP should consider why they want to achieve this functionality and do something different.